# What's wrong with my solution to Chevalier de Méré's problem?

Tags: probability

Consider [Chevalier de Méré's Problem](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Probability/ChevalierDeMere.shtml). In short, given two fair die rolled independently, is it profitable to bet that 1 double six will be rolled in 24 rolls? This is my solution, which is different than the answers on the internet [such as here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/deMeresProblem.html).

Let $S_n$ be the number of double sixes in $n$ rolls. Let $X_i$ be the event that a double six is rolled on the $i$th roll, taking values in $\{s,f\}$ for success (double sixes were rolled) or failure. Then

$$
S_n = \textbf{1}_{X_1=s} + \textbf{1}_{X_2=s} + \dots + \textbf{1}_{X_n=s}
$$

where $\textbf{1}_{X_i=s}$ is an indicator random variable taking values in $\{0,1\}$ depending on whether $X_i$ was a double six or not. By the linearity of expectation, we can write

$$
\textbf{E}[S_n] = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \textbf{E}[\textbf{1}_{X_i=s}] = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \textbf{P}\{X_i=s\} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{36} = \frac{n}{36}
$$

So the *expected number of double sixes in $24$ rolls is $\frac{24}{36} = \frac{2}{3}$.*

Now numerically, this is completely nonsensical. There's no way that the expected number of double sixes is $\frac{2}{3}$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is it nonsense?

Comment: Why shouldn't the answer be $\frac 23$?

Comment: Since each throw has an independent probability of $\frac 1{36}$ of winning you expect $24\times \frac 1{36}$ wins, just as you say.  To be sure, the usual Chevalier problem just asks whether the chance of rolling at least one pair of sixes is greater than $\frac 12$ or not.  Not clear how you hope to get that out of the expectation.

Comment: Oh, I see. I just computed a totally different quantity than other people. Since the expected number of double sixes is less than 1, it's not profitable.

Comment: Your answer is correct for the expected number of wins.  The link you posted gives the probability of winning, which is a different question.

Comment: @gwg I don't think that is obvious, though it may well be true.  In principle the probability of throwing exactly one double six might be $.55$, and the probability of throwing more than one might be $0$  in which case the expected number would be $.55$ which is less than $1$.  It's hard to use expected value to decide these things.

Comment: I suggest studying the "official" answers.  the approaches shown there seem optimal.

Comment: Thanks for following up with the word of caution. I understand the official answers, but I was curious if my approach was okay. Your comment that the expected value can be tricky in this case makes sense.

Comment: If you look again at the second link you posted, the probability of throwing at least one double $6$ in $25$ rolls is $>1/2$ but the expected number of successes is $25/36.$  As @lulu said, expected value is not a good guide.